# Shell command that cycles through lines?

Tags: command-line

Lately, I've often found myself wanting to run some command on the output of another command that has output on several lines.

For example, let's say I have a command that returns a number of file paths each on a new line and I'd like to delete all these files.

Is there a command that can help me do this?

Comment: What environment? Windows? UNIX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs). From the man page:

> xargs reads arguments  from  the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash)  or  newlines,  and executes  the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-arguments followed  by  arguments  read  from  standard  input.

So you can do things like:

```
ls | grep -v '*.cpp' | xargs rm
```

The above command would delete everything in the current directory except `*.cpp` files.

Answer (score 3):

In bash-like shells you can do:

```
rm `your command`
```

or

```
rm $(your command)
```

Comment: This works well until the file names contain spaces, or the list grows too long.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, CMD:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (`your command`) @del "%i"
```

Powershell:

```
your command | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | xargs rm
```

one interesting use (to search a directory for a phrase inside a file)

```
find /path/to/dir | xargs grep "search text"
```

That one isn't related, but it shows how xargs works

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a UNIX-like environment:

To handle spaces in names, use the `-0` flag to xargs. With find:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 dosomething
```

Some other commands have various switches for nul-separated output, usually `-0` or `-z`. If your list is line-oriented, do something like:

```
cat filelist | tr -s '\012\015' '\000' | xargs -0 dosomething
```

Which uses `tr` to translate newlines and linefeeds to nuls, handling UNIX and DOS (and even Mac Classic) line ends and skipping blank lines.

Don't forget that newlines are valid filename characters on most UNIX-like filesystems.

If `dosomething` is complex, you can use bash functions:

```
dosomething() {
    while [ -n "$1" ] ; do
        out="$(basename "$1" .mp3).ogg"
        convert "$1" "converted/$out"
        shift
    done
}

export -f dosomething
```

and invoke `xargs` like:

```
cat filelist | tr -s '\012\015' '\000' | xargs -0 bash -c 'dosomething "$@"' --
```

Note the judicious use of double-quoting to preserve spaces, and that double-quoted strings can be nested inside double-quoted `$()` eval operators.

Within the function, you can write `"$@"` to get a properly quoted argument list to pass to a subprocess:

```
dosomething() {
    command1 preargs "$@" postargs | command2
    command3 "$@"
}
```

You can also use `read` to work line-by-line:

```
cat filelist | while read i ; do something "$i" ; done
```

but xargs gets you all of the args at once.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cat file | while read i; do echo "working on line $i"; done
```

Although you can have trouble with lines having spaces. I never remember how to fix that.
Please note that this command works for every manipulation on a line-by-line basis. Using xargs works only for the example case you asked (and similar cases), but if you can solve your problem with xargs, definitely go for it.

Comment: You're looking for cut. This would print the first column. If you want to get fancier, check out sed and/or awk.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/

cat file | while read i; do FOO=echo $i | cut -f1; echo $FOO; done

(EDIT: moved from answer to comment)